# Парсинг ruSO. Разрешено ли это?

Tags: обсуждение

Каково отношение stack overflow к сайтам, копирующим базу данных участников, а также вопросы и ответы этих участников.

Есть ли какая-то легальная возможность удалить данные с сайта клона, оперевшись на правила ruSO. Или ruSO разрешает такое поведение?

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, контекст чуть более развернуто?